# Grid system issues in Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am new in Twitter Bootstrap and I can't figure out a particular issue in bootstrap 3 that I am running into

The code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>RC</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-11 col-xs-offset-1">
                    <div class="row low-gutter">
                        <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-3">
                            <h1>
                                <span class="rc">RC</span>
                            </h1>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-9">
                            <h2>
                                Text &<br />
                                Some Text
                            </h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6">
                    Some Content
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]
[image]

Now I understand why "Some content" is wrapping onto the next line on the smaller screen because I have used up all the 12 columns of the gird system but according to me when I switch to a wider screen I should be seeing the "Some content" on the on the right hand side of the jumbotron. What am I doing wrong? Have I messed up the grid system logic somehow?

Comment: well, for starters, you use different type of column ordering in your different divs, in one place, you do `col-xs-7 col-sm-9`, then at another place you do `col-md-6` - being consistent will help ;)

Comment: Yeah but that is a nested grid? Isn't that allowed? I mean can't I use another row inside a column and divide it as I please?

Comment: Agreed with @webeno, use for the div of the content class `class="col-md-11`, because col-md-6 is actually 50% of the width of the whole grid, i.e. the space is too narrow.

Comment: @Rohan everything is allowed, but don't be surprised of the inconsistent result ;)

Comment: Okay I got it. The problem was the RC logo. It had some extra padding and that is why it was pushing the the columns on the right side to the next line. I tried using col-md-4 instead of 6 for the second column of the outer row it is working as expected. Thanks anyway everyone.

Comment: Okay, now how do I close a question?

Comment: you can add the answer yourself and accept it, it is allowed. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. The RC logo had some extra padding to it which is why the outer row could not accommodate the 12 columns. I changed the second div of the outer row to `col-md-4` instead of the `col-md-6` and that solved the problem. "Some content" is showing up on the right side now in wider screens.